# Rotate PNG image, and maintain transparent background

Tags: php, image, png, rotation, transparent

I want to rotate an image, but i seem to be unable to maintain the image itself.

This is what i have:

```
// Content type
header('Content-type: image/png');  

$image = 'http://mapning.com/img/plane.png';
$file = imagecreatefrompng($image);
// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($file, $angle, 0);
// Output
imagepng($rotate);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specifically force GD to preserve transparency. Try

```
imagesavealpha($file, TRUE);
```

before the `imagepng()` call.

Comment: Alright, that seems to work a bit. Now the corners are black, and I have found a solution, but this keeps giving me black lines around the original image.

Comment: @RenePot Rene, have you managed to get rid of those black lines? If yes, how did you do it?

Comment: @AndreiOniga sorry, I don't recall, and I don't think I've got the code anymore

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me, in both GD & ImageMagick, is to get the hex/rgb codes for the color of the background you're eventually going to overlay upon. Then, use that as your "background" color. After it's rotated, translate that color to transparent. Then, the little anti-aliased edges will look smooth once you do the overlay.